# The danish character not showing after convert from utf8 to iso-8859-1

Tags: java, android, unicode

I am taking radio stream and trying to read its metadata. It contains some Danish character which are showing as ? marks, so  I tried below conversion

```
String s = new String(streammetadatastring.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

now it removed the ? marks but showing wrong characters. I tried other ways but not getting the right values.

Comment: i also tried with different charsets, but problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line of code like what you posted:

```
String s = new String(streammetadatastring.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16),
                          StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

does not do anything useful.

A [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is a mapping from characters to bytes and vice versa. What you are doing in that line of code is convert a string to bytes using the UTF-16 character encoding, and then you immediately convert the bytes back to a string using the ISO-8859-1 encoding. That will not produce anything useful - the bytes contain UTF-16 encoded characters, not ISO-8859-1 encoded characters.

To make the Danish characters display correctly, you must make sure that wherever you display it (the command prompt window? a Linux shell? an HTML page? a GUI?) uses a font that contains the characters, and that you specify the correct character encoding (how you do that, depends on where you display the characters).

Comment: thanks for information, i am showing that it on a android textview, that textview can show danish charracter. i tried with direct put string there, 
and this conversion making ? marks to charracter just not the right charracter

Comment: In what form are you receiving the data - as bytes from the radio stream? You'll have to find out what character encoding is used in the radio stream. Then convert the bytes to a string using that encoding: `byte[] inputBytes = ...; String text = new String(inputBytes, <charset>);`

Comment: thanks, u were just right, i find the function reading the data has issues
it reading as 
 Html.fromHtml(htmlresponse).toString().replace('\n', (char) 32)
         .replace((char) 160, (char) 32).replace((char) 65532, (char) 
  } else {
   return "";
  }
 }
any suggestion what to change plz?

Comment: It's hard to tell how exactly you should change it without knowing exactly where the data comes from and how it is handled.

Comment: i used a  thirdparty library which return htmlresponse,

Comment: Then it is the library's responsibility to either give you a proper UTF-16 encoded `String` that was internally decoded from the original HTML bytes using the correct charset, or else give you the raw HTML bytes that you can then decode to a `String` yourself using the HTML's charset.